# Swift compiler error contradicts warning when declaring lazy property

Tags: swift, casting, lazy-initialization

```
var rawData: NSDictionary!
lazy var nativeData: NativeData? = {
    return NativeData(JSONDictionary: self.rawData as [NSObject : AnyObject])
}()
```

Results in an error:

> 'NSDictionary!' is not convertible to '[NSObject : AnyObject]'; did
>   you mean to use 'as!' to force downcast?

Ok then...

```
lazy var nativeData: NativeData? = {
    return NativeData(JSONDictionary: self.rawData as! [NSObject : AnyObject])
}()
```

Which gives a warning:

> Forced cast from 'NSDictionary!' to '[NSObject : AnyObject]' always
>   succeeds; did you mean to use 'as'?

Interestingly if I remove the `lazy` and declare `nativeData` as a regular optional, then I can do the `as` cast just fine:

```
obj.nativeData = NativeData(JSONDictionary: obj.rawData as [NSObject : AnyObject])
```

Is this a bug in the compiler? (Xcode 7.3 (7D175))

**Update**

It gets stranger. Here's a contained case.

```
//
//  A.swift
//
import Foundation

class NativeData {
    init(JSONDictionary: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    }
}

func == (lhs: A, rhs: A) -> Bool {
    return lhs.id == rhs.id
}

class A {
    var id: Int64 = 0
    var rawData: NSDictionary!
    lazy var nativeData: NativeData? = {
        return NativeData(JSONDictionary: self.rawData as [NSObject : AnyObject])
    }()
}
```

If you remove the `func ==` operator definition, then the compiler error goes away. (In my actual code, `A` conforms to `Equatable`.) Note that the error doesn't occur if I put this code in a playground.

Comment: Seems like it might be. [File a bug!](http://bugs.swift.org)

Comment: Your first code snippet compiles without errors or warning in my Xcode 7.3 test. Can you add a (minimal) definition of NativeData and  make your problem self-contained?

Comment: I can reproduce the problem only with a different dictionary type, e.g. `[String: AnyObject]` and in that case `as?` or `as!` is the correct solution which triggers no warnings.

Comment: Updated with a somewhat contained case.

Comment: Still cannot reproduce. Your new code examples compiles without errors or warnings. Does it happen in a *new project* with nothing else?